# LUKS password not being requested by dmcrypt / encrypt hook at boot

Tags: dm-crypt, kernel-parameters, mkinitcpio

At boot I see:

```
:: running hook [encrypt]

A password is required to access the  volume:
Command requires device and mapped name as arguments
Command requires device and mapped name as arguments
Command requires device and mapped name as arguments
```

The final message repeats every second.

There is no opportunity for me to enter a password.

I am running Manjaro, based upon Arch.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've probably forgotten to include the required cryptdevice mapped name in the kernel command line parameter.

I had:

`cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX`

However, the second colon-separated field is mandatory, eg:

`cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:root`

If you're using an SSD, and have understood the [implications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_.28SSD.29), for increased performance you may want to use:

`cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:root:allow-discards`